# Slideshow on events calendar site

Tags: php, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery

I am currently developing an events calendar application using ASP.NET MVC and SQL Server and I would like to know how the slideshow for events works on this site - (http://eventful.com/houston/events).

What technologies are involved? Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put it would involve JQuery, and the use of JQuery's ajax helping methods. You would have to return a list of event from a controller action, as JSON perhaps and then have some JQuery code to render them into a slide show.

There may be quite a few plugins out there that achieve what you are looking for, i sugest doing a search on the JQuery plugins site.

Thanks,
Alex.

Answer (score 1):

I thinks the best way to use slideshows is the jquery slideshow. You can find more articles and examples on this topic. 
www.webanddesigners.com/15-jquery-slideshow-and-plugins